# Augmenting Path Algorithm for Maximum Matching

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have a rather cryptic pseudo code version of the augmenting path algorithm for finding a maximum matching in a bipartite graph in my notes.

I m not sure it s correct, and there are some parts that don t make too much sense to me yet.

Unfortunately Cormen is taking a different approach to the problem, so if somebody has experience with the algorithm and knows a very good and reliable source where I can find the correct pseudo code ideally with explanations this would be really appreciated !
(I am looking for the standard algorithm that works in polynomial time on the basis that given a matching M, if there is a bigger matching M' there must be an augmenting path P.)

Comment: Note that there's an auto-completion feature for the tags. In the present case, "(reference-request)" should have been offered when you entered "(reference)".